# I need to declare 2 times the same code but I don't know how

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it's not my field React but I have to develop a little frontend so anyways
I have the next code:

```
const columnsM = useMemo(() => ColumnsMain, [])
    
    const data = useMemo(() => rowData, [])
    const tableInstance = useTable({
       columns: columnsM,
       data: data
    })
    
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      rows,
      prepareRow,
    } = tableInstance
```

And I need to use the same for other table and all works fine despide the last, as I write the next:

```
const columnsDialog= useMemo(() => ColumnsDialog, [])
    
    const data2 = useMemo(() => rowDataDialog, [])
    const tableInstanceDialog = useTable({
       columns: columnsDialog,
       data: data2
    })
    
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      rows,
      prepareRow,
    } = tableInstanceDialog
```

but it gives me an error saying that getTableProps is already defined and so...
any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know reach but I feel the issue is vairbale name 'getTableProps' is being tried to be declared again, which is not allowed is most languages, eg you cant do two let a ; let a in the same block scope.

What you might be able to do is rename it as soon as you create it so in second time.
Eg:           
const {
  getTableProps: newName,
  getTableBodyProps,
  headerGroups,
  rows,
  prepareRow,
} = tableInstanceDialog

Comment: yes! That was! 
Much thanks!